# What is the fastest distributed Caching Solution for .net?

Tags: asp.net, caching, distributed-caching

What caching solution will give me the best results both in terms of requests per second that it can handle and in terms of request latency?

Comment: Exactly what do you expect to cache?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question cause it's a bit open ended but take a peek at Project "Velocity" - http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/

Here's a link to an entry regarding performance:
http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/archive/2009/09/30/griddynamics-benchmark-on-velocity.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Memcached at http://www.danga.com/memcached. It's open source and you can find clients in most languages. I use the C# client.

I use memcached in a server farm as a replacement for the built in asp.net cache, which is not farm friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out a couple of .NET-clients for [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) and think [BeITMemcached](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/)  and [enyim](http://memcached.enyim.com/) seems to be the fastest and most reliable ones. I used [NorthScale Memcached Server](http://labs.northscale.com/memcached-packages/) that worked very well both for 64 bits as for 32 bits Windows servers.